# Determine if $\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\sqrt{n^2+4}-\sqrt{n^2-4})$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Determine if the series is convergent.
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\sqrt{n^2+4}-\sqrt{n^2-4})$$

I'm considering using the Limit Comparison test but I can't decide on a p-series to use. I conjugated the function and i got to.
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{8}{(\sqrt{n^2+4}+\sqrt{n^2-4})}$$
The denominator is confusing me. I'm going to guess with a $p=2$ p-series but it's really confusing.

I tried this:
$$n^2+4n+4\ge n^2+4 \implies n+2\ge \sqrt{n^2+4}$$
$$n^2\ge n^2-4\implies n\ge \sqrt{n^2-4}$$

But i'm stuck
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Use something like ${8\over \sqrt{n^2+4} +\sqrt{n^2-4}}\ge {8\over 2\sqrt{2n^2}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep going.  The inequalities you derived imply

$${8\over\sqrt{n^2+4}+\sqrt{n^2-4}}\ge {8\over2n+2}={4\over n+1}$$

Comment: Your inequalities actually did a nice job of getting rid of the square roots.  If you like, you can simplify things further by noting that ${4\over n+1}\gt{1\over n}$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Couldn't see the connection between my inequalities and your result just now. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Compare it to series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.

$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+4}-\sqrt{n^2-4}}{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{8n}{\sqrt{n^2+4}+\sqrt{n^2-4}} =\\
= \frac{8}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{n^2}}+\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{n^2}}} $

And it's equal to $4$, if $n\to\infty$.
(Of course, it works only if you have studied so far. In not, see other answers for hint.)

Comment: I think I can understand but why is that equal to 1. Shouldn't it be equals to 4?

Comment: You're completely right. My apologies about the mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! I've tested others along with the one I proposed and all results in a p-value greater than 0. So given all the series i tested against converges to zero, then this series will converge as well. is that a correct conclusion? Sorry for the multitudes of questions, just learnt this topic.

Comment: @Danxe, the p-value threshold for convergence is 1, not 0.  The harmonic series $\sum{1\over n}$ does *not* converge!

Comment: @BarryCipra Oh right! My mind went to limit of $\frac{1}{n}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*HINT*

Consider the sum :
$$\sum \frac{1}{2n} < \sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}-4}+\sqrt{n^{2}+4}}$$

That's true for $n \ge 2$.